# Dynamic require with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I need to require relative file and assign it to constant. But instead of hardcoded filename, I want to use variable.

```
const clientName = "google"; // Its coming from arvg
const client = require("./clients/" + clientName);
```

Is it OK or may be NodeJS has some other recommended ways? I use CommonJS syntax.

Comment: `require()` is a regular function that takes a string parameter. It does neither know nor care how you put together the string that you pass to it.

Comment: Is it possible to use require inside another function? And expose required object outside this function to module level.

Comment: That should be easy to find out by trying it.

Comment: require(`./clients/${clientName}`) will work

Comment: Works just fine.  Not sure what you're really asking for help with?

Answer (score -1):

You can use dynamic import. Refer this doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Comment: No, they can't. They said they were using CommonJS (which doesn't support `import`)