# Require file dynamically by variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react-native project I am trying to require images from a variable, but I am getting an error: This call is not symbolicated. If I hardcode the string in require, the import works.

```
const exampleImagesIos = ["./example-images/example-ios-1.png", "./example-images/example-ios-2.png"]

<Swiper>
{exampleImagesIos.map((item, i) => (
                      <View key={i} style={styles.exampleImgContainer2}>
                        <Image style={styles.exampleImgstyle2}
                          source={require(item)}
                        />
                      </View>
                    ))}
</Swiper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic imports does not work in require it only works in import. see [Diff between Require and import](https://flexiple.com/javascript/javascript-require-vs-import/)

so you have to pass static value you can use this

```
const exampleImagesIos = [require("./example-images/example-ios-1.png"), require("./example-images/example-ios-2.png")]
```

and use the direct item in source of image

see this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70145093/dynamic-require-with-nodejs) for more details